# API Routing SPA

Tags: spring-webflux

I'm looking for a solution to redirect all non-server defined routes to index.html.
You can do this by matching

```
GET("/**") { ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).syncBody(indexHtml) }
```

The issue with this approach is that it will override all server defined routes, including static files.

Comment: this is a broad question; we can't decide for you how your application should work. Can you explain in details how the mapping logic should work wrt static resources, 404 responses, API calls, etc. Also, are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes, Spring Boot 2. I would like static content to be served as it would out of the box. The same for API routes ideally, but I would be willing to gather them all under /api. Basically I want the default routing, only that all routes that are not resolved should instead return index.html